# clarkwest: Clark and West's (2006, 2007) Out-of-Sample Test

Tags: r

how works the clark and west test Out-of-Sample Test in Rstudio?
I want to test, if my linear model (lm) with out-of-sample prediction values (platinum prices) better is than a Zero-Model/Model with 0-return.

In Rstudio Help, i found the package "OOS" with function

```
forecast_comparison(
  Data,
  baseline.forecast,
  test = "ER",
  loss = "MSE",
  horizon = NULL
)

datafinal_Pt$baseline_In_Pt <- rep(0, length(datafinal_Pt$vorhersagenPt)) 

comparisonData <- data.frame (
  date = datafinal_Pt$Date, 
  observed = datafinal_Pt$logreturnPt, 
  model_forecast = datafinal_Pt$vorhersagenPt, 
  baseline = datafinal_Pt$baseline_In_Pt
) 

result <- forecast_comparison(
  Data = comparisonData, 
  baseline.forecast = "baseline" , 
  test = "CM", horizon = 1
)

Error in dplyr::select(): ! Selections can't have missing values.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
```

but this is not working, i really need help please.
I only want to test how good my lm is? how good my prediction values are?

grateful for any tip and help.

Thanks a lot.

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(8824, 8855, 8885, 8916, 8946, 8977), class = "Date"), observed = c(0.0163341112684792, 0.0155673927308728, -0.00967871792568369, 0.0048143694112221, 0.00750364400740202, 0.0251949482068637), model_forecast = c(0.0138322343057244, 0.0134730149230344, -0.00172029773616844, 0.0287367367817533, 0.01983307646487, 0.0276670199321105 ), baseline = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In what way is your current attempt not working?  Do you get errors or warnings?  if so, what are they?  Do you get output but feel that it doesn't make sense?  If so, what is the output and why do you feel it is wrong?  We may well need to see (some of) your data.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: 'datafinal_Pt$baseline_In_Pt <- rep(0, length(datafinal_Pt$vorhersagenPt))
comparisonData <- data.frame (date = datafinal_Pt$Date, observed = datafinal_Pt$logreturnPt, model_forecast = datafinal_Pt$vorhersagenPt, baseline = datafinal_Pt$baseline_In_Pt)

result <- forecast_comparison(Data = comparisonData, baseline.forecast = "baseline" , test = "CM", horizon = 1)'.                                                                                  Error in `dplyr::select()`:
! Selections can't have missing values.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Thank you.  We are making progress.  The error suggests you *may* have misspelt the name of a column in your `comparisonData` data frame.  So we need to see (some of) it. So please add the output from `dput(head(comparisonData))` to your question.  Please read - and  follow - the advice in the link I gave you earlier.

Comment: structure(list(date = structure(c(8824, 8855, 8885, 8916, 8946, 
8977), class = "Date"), observed = c(0.0163341112684792, 0.0155673927308728, 
-0.00967871792568369, 0.0048143694112221, 0.00750364400740202, 
0.0251949482068637), model_forecast = c(0.0138322343057244, 0.0134730149230344, 
-0.00172029773616844, 0.0287367367817533, 0.01983307646487, 0.0276670199321105
), baseline = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
_date has the  class "Date, so i don't know why there a numbers instead_

Comment: 1. thank you for helping, 2. i read the link, what should i change?